# Can I start a ManagedThread in a Singleton Enterprise Java Bean?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-ee-7

I'm trying to start a thread in a Singleton EJB but `java.lang.IllegalStateException` is being thrown. This is my (cut-down) class:

```
Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class WatcherEJB {


    @Resource(name = "concurrent/masterActionsThreadFactor")
    ManagedThreadFactory threadFactory;

    Thread watcherThread;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startUp() {

        //Setup the listener using the ThreadFactory
        watcherThread = threadFactory.newThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //System.out.println("Watcher Thread started");
            }
        });
        watcherThread.start(); //java.lang.IllegalStateException thrown here
    } 
}
```

I'm assuming that there's a problem with *when* I'm trying to start the Thread object or does Java EE 7 not allow Managed threads in singletons?

Comment: @perissf: Working with threads in the EJB container is discouraged in **JAVA EE 6 and prior**. In **JAVA EE 7** You can work with threads using `ManagedThreadFactory`, `ManagedExecutorService` and  `ManagedScheduledExecutorService`. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/concurrency-utilities.htm#GKJIQ8

Comment: You are right. I have never worked on this yet. I am going to remove the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What application server do You use?

If it's WildFly You probably run into this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2343

Comment: It's Glassfish 4. Whilst I'm only a beginner in the field of Java 7 EE I cannot see a reason why this should not work. There is nothing I see in the docs to say what I am doing is prohibited.

Comment: The issue you posted describes what I see too so it may not be implementation specific?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this thread when looking for a solution and I thought that I would post this link to a thread which I believe answers the question. I know it has been a while since this question was asked but it should be useful for future reference!

[Glassfish 4 - Using Concurrency API to create Managed Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900826/glassfish-4-using-concurrency-api-to-create-managed-threads)