# Glassfish 4 - Using Concurrency API to create Managed Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, glassfish, java-ee-7

I'm trying to use the new Concurrency API to inject a [ManagedThreadFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedThreadFactory.html) and use it per [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/concurrency-utilities006.htm).

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Demo {
    @Resource(name="concurrent/__DefaultManagedThreadFactory") ManagedThreadFactory threadFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startup() {
        threadFactory.newThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Do something.");
                }
            }
        ).start();
    }
}
```

I'm developing in Eclipse using the Glassfish plugin.  When I republish after making a change, I always get this line in the server log.  It appears once for every call to start() we make:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module (my application) is disabled
```

It's not actually throwing an IllegalStateException, just reporting that one has been thrown (and caught) inside Glassfish.  The application deploys normally, but none of the threads start.  If I subsequently republish and second time, the "error" goes away and the threads start as expected.

When I try to deploy the application to a "real" Glassfish setup (without Eclipse), it always reports successful deployment, and the logs do not contain the "error".  But it still does not start the threads (even with repeated deployments).

Am I using the Concurrency API correctly?  Could it be a configuration problem?  For the record, I get the same behavior if I use a ManagedExcecutorService instead.

---

*For the record, this question was asked a few months ago here: [Can I start a ManagedThread in a Singleton Enterprise Java Bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446682/can-i-start-a-managedthread-in-a-singleton-enterprise-java-bean), but it was not really answered and I don't have the reputation yet to do anything but ask it again.  Sorry!*

---

UPDATE: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360042/3593206) by [Per-Axel Felth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806345/per-axel-felth)  works.  Thank you!  I did some refactoring of that solution to attempt to isolate the workaround code from my original application logic:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Demo {

    @Resource(name="java:comp/DefaultManagedThreadFactory") ManagedThreadFactory threadFactory;
    @EJB private ConcurrencyInitializer concurrencyInitializer;
    @EJB private Demo self;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startup() {
        self.startThread();
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void startThread() {
        //This line applies the workaround
        concurrencyInitializer.init();

        //Everything beyond this point is my original application logic
        threadFactory.newThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Do something.");
                }
            }
        ).start();            
    }

}
```

```
/**
 * A utility class used to get around a bug in Glassfish that allows
 * Concurrency resources (ManagedThreadFactory, ManagedExecutorService, etc)
 * to be injected before they are ready to be used. 
 * 
 * Derived from solution by Per-Axel Felth in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900826/glassfish-4-using-concurrency-api-to-create-managed-threads
 */
@Singleton
public class ConcurrencyInitializer {
    /**
     * The number of milliseconds to wait before try to 
     */
    public static final long RETRY_DELAY = 500L;

    /**
     * The maximum number of concurrency attempts to make before failing
     */
    public static final int MAX_RETRIES = 20;

    /**
     * Repeatedly attempts to submit a Runnable task to an injected ManagedExecutorService
     * to trigger the readying of the Concurrency resources.
     * 
     * @return true if successful (Concurrency resources are now ready for use),
     *         false if timed out instead
     */
    public boolean init() {
        final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        int i = 0;

        try {
            while (!done.get() && i++ < MAX_RETRIES) {
                executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        done.set(true);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(RETRY_DELAY);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            //Do nothing.
        } 

        return done.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to a Glassfish bug. I ran into the same bug myself some time ago and built a workaround. Thing is, the thread factory is injected alright, but if you use it "too early" you'll end up with an IllegalStateException.

My workaround code is listed below. It uses an injected executor service to detect when app is loaded and concurrency utils are available and then executes the actual startup logic in method `init`.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Demo {

    @Resource(name = "concurrent/__DefaultManagedThreadFactory")
    ManagedThreadFactory threadFactory;
    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService executorService;
    @EJB
    Demo me;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startup() {

        me.waitAndInitialize();
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<?> waitAndInitialize() {
        try {
            final AtomicInteger done = new AtomicInteger(0);
            int i = 0;

            while (done.intValue() == 0 && i < 20) {
                System.out.println("Is executor service up?");

                i++;

                executorService.submit(
                        new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                int incrementAndGet = done.incrementAndGet();
                                System.out.println("Run by executorservice");
                            }
                        });
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }

            if (done.intValue() == 0) {
                Logger.getAnonymousLogger().severe("Waited a long time for the ExecutorService do become ready, but it never did. Will not initialize!");
            } else {
                init();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception in waitAndInitialize: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return new AsyncResult<>(null);
    }

    private void init() {
        threadFactory.newThread(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Do something.");
                    }
                }
        ).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your ManagedThreadFactory is not being injected correctly so the "Demo" component is not started.

The Java EE 7 spec mandates that a managed thread factory be made available in JNDI with the name "java:comp/DefaultManagedThreadFactory", therefore try changing @Resource to

```
@Resource(name="java:comp/DefaultManagedThreadFactory")
```

I'm not familiar with Glassfish (I'm a WildFly kind of guy) but you may not see this reference in any JNDI tree display. It may be linked internally to "concurrent/__DefaultManagedThreadFactory" (which is not a resource name btw).

Failing that you can also try

```
@Resource(lookup="concurrent/__DefaultManagedThreadFactory")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I changed the name of the injected @Resource, but am still getting the same behavior.  But I think you're right, it seems that the ManagedThreadFactory is not being injected correctly.